# AzureAD Bearer Authentication .Net Core - Deployed on IIS - Not working

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-active-directory

We have a.Net core 2.1 application which is using BearerAuthenticationScheme. When we run this application in debug we can call the APIs after getting a valid token from Azure AD.  Once we publish this application and deploy this on IIS server it gives error 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.

Do we have to do any specific IIS settings for our APIs to accept BearerTokens?

Looking forward to some assistance on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: One thing you can try is collect a failed request trace from IIS. There you can see on what module the request was stopped.